# Unity Can not build when adding Ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem for a few days that I can't solve.
When I add to my project(that work fine) a unity ads or admob using google package.
After I add one of this package and try to build my project for android I get an error with my gradle:

```
Exception: Gradle install not valid
Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle..ctor (System.String gradleLauncherPath, System.Int32 
jvmHeapSize) (at <aa400196d78d4a0aab4d78eb144a59f3>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.CreateGradleInstance () (at 
<62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ExecuteWarmup (System.String stagingArea) 
(at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess 
(UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, 
AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at 
<62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess 
(UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& 
outProperties) (at <62de111f18d242d586f9a078a33b1ba2>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup 
targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String 
installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, 
System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry 
usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at 
<11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

I tried to download a gradle and replace it in my project but this dont solve it.
I tried copy the gradle location on the external tools and uncheck and copy the location and this not work.
I even try to open a new project using the monitaztion sample of unity and still get the same error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was with version 2021.3.16, and I try to install another version(2021.3.13) and now its work.
I Saw that the gradle is inside the unity folder so I thought that if I reinstall the unity or install another veraion it should fix it, or maybe its a bug in veraion 2021.3.16.